# Young adult Christian fantasy series about 2-5 kids who traveled to an alternate world and met strange sentient creatures

Tags: story-identification, christian

I think it was a book series, possibly published in 70s-90s, but may have been a TV show or movie. It was about 2-5 kids who traveled to an alternate world and met strange sentient creatures. One of the kids was a girl, and there was at least one boy, and I think they were younger than teens. The stories may have begun with one of the kids doing something wrong (like bullying), or having a question about faith or the Bible, and then learning a moral at the end. I'm not completely sure about the first part, but I do think there was a moral or point at the end.

In one of the stories, the kids were separated, and the girl went to a sort of creation operating center.  Some kind of strange creature (and a friend of the adventurers) was working in this center.  The girl was allowed to experiment with creating two sentient creatures of her own design and watched them on a large table.  I think it was an underwater world, and the people the girl created lived underwater. Like the Garden of Eden, her rules for the creations were that they could do whatever they wanted, but they must stay away from the edge of the table.  Eventually enjoying their creator wasn't enough, and the girl's creatures became divided and exhibited classic Christian archetypes: rebel and burdened by faith.  The rebel set out to find the edge of the world (table).  The girl was concerned for him because he would fall off the edge and die, so she tried to send signs and walls to block his way, but he would pass them, go around, or even climb over the walls.  The other creature came following behind, picking up every warning message from the main character, and being weighed down to the point of sinking into the sand.  The rebel reaches the edge of the world, leans precariously over, and then falls.  The girl catches him and cries over his limp form.  She discovered how God must feel when his beloved creation strays from his will for them.

All the books (or episodes) were Christian/God-centered, and featured a Christian moral or point at the end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I have been searching for this book for many years now. I even came across this link a bit back in one of my searches and knew I wasn't crazy and dreaming up a book because you described the exact same scene that I remembered. Today I finally was able to figure out what the book was and the first thing I did was try to track down this post again so I could let you know.

They changed the name of the series. It used to be called *Journeys to Fayrah* by Bill Myers. It's now called *[The Bloodstone Chronicles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0310246849)* and they combined the series into one book.

I'm so incredibly excited that I found it and I've already bought it so I can reread the series. I hope that you enjoy!!!

It also goes by the name *The Imaging Chronicles*. The description in the question appears to correspond the the volume *The Experiment*.

See [the author's website](http://billmyersbooks.com/imager-experiment.php).

Comment: Excellent work! Expect a bonus gift tomorrow.

Comment: Amazing!  It definitely sounds familiar, so I'm going to mark this one answered and check out the book.  Thanks!